# Flurry now reporting half as many sessions - What happened on 31 March?

Tags: android, session, flurry

We've been using Flurry to track volumes of sessions, active users, etc for an Android app for 9 months.  The results have always been sensible (ie no abrupt changes or swings that couldn't be explained).  However at the end of March we witnessed a 50% reduction in the number of sessions (top figure) while active users (bottom figure) stayed nice and steady.

I was wondering if the integration of Flurry into Yahoo may have caused Flurry to redefine what it counts as a session.

Has anyone else noticed similar behavior on or about the beginning of March?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We aren't aware of any change on our side that would cause the dramatic drop in sessions. If there were some change your iOS app would also be impacted.

We followed up on your support ticket and we're looking forward to digging into this with you.